# Is it better to average each reading before applying a formula, or apply the formula to each set of readings and then average?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

If $f$ is some function of independent variables $a,b ...z$ and readings of each of them have some inherent (random and systematic) error, would it better to average the readings of each variable and then apply $f$, or apply $f$ to each set of readings and then average $f$? I.e. which of $$1)\ \ \ f(\bar{a},\bar{b},...\bar{z})$$
$$2)\ \ \overline{f(a,b,...z)}$$ would minimise the error in $f$ in general?

Comment: In general $\overline{f(x)}\neq f(\bar{x})$, so it depends on your specific formula you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself: What would I like to know? Usually, we are most interested  in the end result $y=f(x)$ and not in the intermediate result $x$. Therefore, we are interested in the distribution/average value/standard deviation etc. of the end result. However, $f(\bar x)$ is *not* the average value the end result, and $f(\bar x \pm  2\cdot\sigma_x)$ is not the 95% confidence interval of the end result. Thus, usually it makes sense to first calculate the end result for each data point $y_i = f(x_i)$, and then to apply the statistics of interests, e.g. the average or the standard deviation.